# С++ - Матрица : найти максимальный отрицательный элемент с четными индексами

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Не получается вывести максимальный отрицательный элемент с четными индексами.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;

    void main()
    {
        setlocale(0, "rus");
        int i, j, n, m;
        int mas[30][30];
        double s1, s2;

        cout << "Размер матрицы n \n";
        cin >> n;
        cout << "Размер матрицы m \n";
        cin >> m;
        cout << "\n\n";


        srand(time(0));


        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                mas[i][j] = rand() % 101 - 50;


        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                cout << mas[i][j] << "\t";
            cout << "\n";
        }
        int count = 0;
        int ch[30];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ch[i] = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (mas[i][j] < 0) {
                    count++;
                    cout << "Координаты :" << " i = " << i + 1 << "  " << " j = " << j + 1 << endl;
                }
                if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0 && (j + 1) % 2 == 0 && mas[i][j] < 0) { ch[i] = mas[i][j]; }
            }
        }
        int max = ch[0];
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (max < ch[i]) {
                max = ch[i];

                cout << " Max = " << max << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << " Кол-во отрицательных чисел : " << count << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: А что такое "парные индексы"?

Comment: @ Harry , скорее всего те, которые делятся на 2 без остатка.

Comment: А, а то я подумал, что какие-то сопряженные там...

Answer (score 1):

Я немного подработал, посмотрите. Массив `ch` совсем не нужен, ищу среди отрицательных элементов наибольший - не по модулю, а именно наибольший, так ведь вас понимать надо?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void main() {
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int i, j, n, m;
    int mas[30][30];
    double s1, s2;
    cout << "Размер матрицы n \n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Размер матрицы m \n";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "\n\n";
    srand(time(0));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            mas[i][j] = rand() % 101 - 50;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << mas[i][j] << "\t";

        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    int count = 0;
    int max = INT_MIN;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i += 2) {
        for (j = 1; j < m; j += 2) {
            if (mas[i][j] < 0) {
                count++;
                cout << "Координаты :" << " i = " << i << "  " << " j = " << j <<
                     endl;

                if (max < mas[i][j]) max = mas[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << " Max = " << max << endl;
    cout << " Кол-во отрицательных чисел : " << count << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо!Работает.